# How to set value in CSV file in Karate

Tags: api, karate

I am reading some test userid and password from csv file. and want to store id(combination of id and password and some random text) for each userid and password using karate.

Feature: setid

Scenario Outline: set authid

```
* def authId = '<username>' + '<password>' + 'test'

* print authId

* set <id> = authId

Examples:

  | read('testdata.csv') |
```

testdata.csv

username,password,id

shivam,abc,

rahul,pqr,

While running above code i am getting error datatest.feature:5 - no step-definition method match found for: set  = authId

Can anyone help me where i am missing.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you can't update a CSV data source like that. Please use Java code, as what you seem to be trying to do is something specific and not normal API testing related.

Comment: Thanks Peter. is there any other way to set value in some other data source(json files or some table not csv file) for each row.

I have tried with below code as but could not succedd

Feature: setid

    Scenario Outline: setauthid

      * json t =  __row

      * print t.name

      * set t.status = "pass"


      Examples:
        | name   | country  | status |
        | monza  | Italy    |        |
        | spa    | Belgium  |        |
        | sepang | Malaysia |        |
this is working fine but not setting a status.

Comment: there are many ways if you read the docs. nobody ever asks this question. so please explain what you are trying to do (in a new question if needed). most likely there is an easy way to do it in karate